# cannot access my own computer through My Network Places

Tags: windows-xp, netbios, workgroup, windows-networking

My home Windows XP Pro SP3 machine is DHCP client receiving configurations from ISP.

Trying to access in WindowsExplorer

-My Network Places

```
 - Microsoft Windows Network
```

shows Workgroup with a delay of 3 min and then popups messagebox:

---

### Microsoft Windows Network

Workgroup is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.The list of servers for this workgroup is not currently available

---

OK

---

I am logged-in as local machine Administrator.

The internet is accessible (I am writing this post through it)

The Firewall is disabled

The "Computer Bowser" and all networking services, I could find, are running

Control Panel --> Network Connections --> Properties (of connection) ---> Internet Protocol (TCP/IP), btn Properties ---> ---> tab General, btn "Advanced..." --> tab WINS--> rbtn "Enable NetBIOS  over TCP/IP" checked

Why cannot I access my own PC (and shares on it) through
My Network Places

What is the possible problem?

How to daignose the problem?

Comment: Where are you trying to log in from?  What IP addresses exist on your home machine, and the remote machine?

Comment: In windows Explorer I am trying to navigate the tree 
My Network Places --> Microsoft Windows Network
It shows only my own Workgroup (with a delay of 3 min and then popups messagebox) but I cannot navigate to my own PC there getting error: "Workgroup is not accessible", see original post. Was not it written in my original post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was that I manually entered incorrect WINS ip which prevented WINS ip well as node type from DHCP (though all the rest NIC settings were dynamic).

Note that the presence of manual WINS ip entry also resulted in "Node Type: Peer-Peer" which is possibly due to the fact that I installed Networking Services (don't remeber - from from Windows XP Support Tools) and among them

PNRPSvc (Peer Name Resolution Protocol)

Peer-to-Peer service (Enables Peer-to-Peer Networking Services. Windows Firewall will be configured to allow Peer-to-Peer Networking Connections)

Deleting maual WINS ip changed Node Type to Unknown by DHCP and permitted communication in workgroup blocked by (broken) WINS ip.